# SilverLIght objects not identified through Selenium Webdriver. Can you please suggest how to proceed

Tags: java, silverlight, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Webdriver does not identify the xpath : //object[@id='slPlugin2']. Getting "NoSuch Element exception"

```
***<table class="imgTable photoTable" cellspacing="0">

<tbody>

<tr>

<td colspan="10">

<div id="fileUploadControl312" class="fileUpload t-toolbar t-grid-toolbar t-grid-top" style="display: block;">

<object id="slPlugin2" width="127" height="32" data="data:application/x-silverlight," type="application/x-silverlight">

<param value="white" name="background"/>
<param value="/LMM/ClientBin/FileUpload.xap" name="source"/>
<param value="Url =https://lmmwipqa.blob.core.windows.net/uploads?se=2014-04-14T06%3A45%3A03Z&sr=c&sp=w&sig=tUbcB6GkW6d9Gjo23WKru5W7j%2BsalbOUnJUj7N197kg%3D, Parent =fileUploadControl312, Caption =Add Photo" name="initParams"/>

</object>
</div>
<br/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>****
```

Comment: Can you post you line of code that uses the XPath?

Comment: ff.findElement(By.xpath("//object[@id='slPlugin2']")).click();

Comment: button on which click is performed is silverlight object. hence webdriver is bot recognising it. Is there any way to make webdriver recognise silverlight object?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can not directly access a Silverlight element. 
Read [this](https://problemsimet.wordpress.com/2013/01/22/silverlight-5-apllication-testing-with-selenium/) or [this](https://code.google.com/p/silverlight-selenium/). It will get you started.